# Lambda can't find the file test_lambda.js. Make sure that your handler upholds the format: file-name.method

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-sqs

I am facing an issue with my AWS Lambda trigger function where the console appears to say `Lambda can't find the file test_lambda.js. Make sure that your handler upholds the format: file-name.method.`

Here is my relevant code. Here is the lambda function itself -

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "development_lambda" {
  function_name = "test_lambda"
  role          = "${aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn}"
  handler       = "test_lambda"
  runtime = "nodejs10.x"

  filename      = "test_lambda.js.zip"
  source_code_hash = "${filebase64sha256("test_lambda.js.zip")}"

  timeout = 10

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids         = flatten(["${private_subnet_ids}"])
    security_group_ids = flatten(["${security_group_id}"])
  }

  environment {
    variables = {
      env = "localhost"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the event source mapping code -

```
resource "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping" "event_source_mapping" {
  event_source_arn = "${aws_sqs_queue.development-queue.arn}"
  enabled          = true
  function_name    = "${aws_lambda_function.development_lambda.arn}"
  batch_size       = 10
}
```

And here is the lambda handler in file `test_lambda.js`

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log("Lambda test");
    callback(null, 'In Lambda');
};
```

I also have a test_lambda.js.zip in the same path.

What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your handler should be `test_lambda.handler`.

Answer (score 0):

you could see under the Basic Settings info. on the AWS Lambda Console, the Handler should be defined as: **file-name.method** like file-name.handler

If Python, filename is **index.py** and the definition body inside the Code as
**def lambda_handler(event, context):**

```
index.lambda_handler
```

If Node.js, filename is **lambda_function.js** and the definition body defined as
 **exports.handler = async (event) =>**

```
lambda_function.handler
```